# Using assertTrue(==) vs assertEqual in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

In the Python `unittest` module, are there any advantages or disadvantages of using `assertTrue()` vs. `assertEqual()` in the following case?

```
self.assertTrue(a == b)
self.assertEqual(a, b)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Always use `assertEqual()`, as it *customizes failure output*.

The method delegates to various helper methods to show you how, for example, two strings or two lists differ when the assertion fails, provided the type of both arguments match and have a type-specific helper method registered.

`assertTrue()` can only tell you about the assertion failing, not show you why.

From the [`assertEqual()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual):

> In addition, if *first* and *second* are the exact same type and one of `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `set`, `frozenset` or `str` or any type that a subclass registers with `addTypeEqualityFunc()` the type-specific equality function will be called in order to generate a more useful default error message (see also the [list of type-specific methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#type-specific-methods)).

Only use `assertTrue()` if there is no more specific assertion available.

Comment: well, if you have a method returning booleans, I don't see any reason to use assertEqual

Comment: @Ed_: that's not what the question is asking about, however. The answer addresses the stated question, not *when should I use `assertTrue`* without further context.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check a value other than True choose `assertEqual` to get a meaningful error message. It's also more readable in my opinion as you define what is the expected part compared to the value you want to check.

Choose `assertTrue` over `assertEqual` if you want to check for a True boolean result such as `assertTrue(user.hasAdminRole())`

Comment: That’s not what was asked. Yes, the point of `assertTrue()` is to make an assertion about the truth value of an expression. The question applies specifically to `==` equality testing.

Comment: You probably want to use assertIs(True, xxx) for the hasAdminRole example, not assertTrue. Otherwise user.hasAdminRole could return 37 and pass, which is probably not what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62117162/what-is-the-difference-between-assertis-and-asserttrue-in-unittest-module-when