# What is the difference between assertIs and assertTrue in unittest module, when these methods are applied on True values?

Tags: python, unit-testing

My working environment:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bits)
Python version: 3.8.0 (64 bits)
```

I've a question about the unittest documentation, more precisely, the difference between `assertTrue` and `assertIs` methods. Here is what the online documentation says:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

> `assertTrue(expr, msg=None)`
>
> `assertFalse(expr, msg=None)`
>
> Test that expr is true (or false).
>
> Note that this is equivalent to bool(expr) is True and  not to expr is
>   True (use `assertIs(expr, True)` for the latter).

I don't really understand the difference, that is, in the case where I have a boolean type with a True value, then why should I use `assertIs` instead of `assertTrue`? Given that `bool(True) is True` also returns the True boolean value I don't see the difference and impact on tests. I'd appreciate if you could kindly make some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question you have to understand the difference between `is` and `==` comparison operators, imagine you have two different boys, but they are both Peters, they have the same name so `==` will give you true, but `is` will give you False, because they are not one person.

```py
import unittest


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_your_func(self):
        x = MyClass(5)
        y = MyClass(5)
        z = x
        print(x is y)  # False x is not y, they are separate object
        print(x == y)  # True 5 == 5 
        print(x is z)  # True, because z is the reference to the same object
        print(z == y)  # True 5 == 5
        # self.assertIs(x, y)  # if you uncomment the line you'll get error
        self.assertIs(x, z)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As per `AssertTrue`m it has absolutely different purpose to use, e.g. `if []:` is `False` and `if [1]` is `True`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is actually the first time that I see the use of redefinition of def __eq__(self, other). Indeed, it is a matter of interpretation based on how this method has been defined/redefined by the user and then, obviously the equality check based on reference and the equality check based solely on attributes' values are not the same. So AssertTrue just checks that the tested value, can be evaluated to True boolean value but assertIs checks that the tested parameter(= an object) is actually a reference to the Python True object. Do I understand correctly now?

Comment: Each python object has address in memory, ```is``` checks if it two references points to the same memory address. To see it just print ```x, y, z``` from my example and you'll see addressed of the objects (until you define ```__repr__``` for the class. ```AssertTrue``` has absolutely different use case, e.g. you can check if ```list``` or ```dict``` has elements inside if yes, you'll get True. I defined ```__eq__``` in my class because Python does not know how to use ```==``` to compare class objects defined by user.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically right - in most cases in tests you will probably use `assertTrue` for the check instead of `assertIs(True)`.

The only really useful case where you actually need `assertIs(True)` would be if you want to check that the checked expression actually returns a `bool` value, e.g.:

```python
def test_bool(self):
    a = True
    b = 1
    self.assertTrue(a)
    self.assertIs(a, True)
    self.assertTrue(b)
    self.assertIsNot(b, True)
```

This could be interesting if you have a function that may return values of different types, and you want to ensure that it returns a concrete `bool` value. Consider a (nonsense) function:

```python
def fct(param):
    if param < 0:
        return False
    if param > 0:
        return True
    return 42

...

def test_fct(self):
    assertTrue(fct(1))  # will not ensure that it returns True
    assertTrue(fct(0))  # also passes
    assertIs(True, fct(1))  # passes as intended
    assertIs(True, fct(0))  # fails, as it should
```

It can also help to ensure that your tested function that is supposed to return a `bool` value actually does that (and not just some value that would evaluate to `True` or `False`, like `None` or a number, due to some bug).

This all works of course because (like `None`), `True` and `False` are singleton objects, e.g. there is always only one of each of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Very interesting example and clear explanation. In fact I hadn't taken into account that being evaluated to a True value and being explicitely defined and declared as boolean value are not exactly the same thing. Very subtle point. Thanks a lot for your help and making this clear.